# Pi for non mathematician

Tags: coordinate-systems, pi

I've been long gone from math (shamefully) and have trouble using some quite familiar concepts...

Consider the following picture in which I render **two circles** with radius 32 (`2`) on a plane of **1024 by 1024** (`1`).

I chose a point at which I render the first circle **[x,y]** (`3`).

I choose to render another circle exactly 1 radius above the first circle.

**How do I calculate `4`? Which is the intersection of the two circles? (can be left or right side).**

> I understand I can calculate the circumference and divide it by six to get the distance from the center of the upper circle to the intersection. But I need coordinates.

Any guide will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You know that the distance from $2$ to $3$ is $r$. Also the distance from $2$ to $4$. And in addition, the distance from $4$ to $3$. What you have is an equilateral triangle of side length $r$.

Comment: By symmetry the vertical position of $[4]$ will be given by half the sum of the ordinates of $[2]$ and $[3]$ $y_4=\frac 12(y_2+y_3)=y2+\dfrac r2$.  
Further the center of $[2]$ and $[3]$ form and equilateral triangle with $[4]$ so that $x_4=x_2- \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}3\right)\cdot r=x_2-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}2\cdot r$

Comment: I like all answers in their own respect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the center of the first circle $(x_1, y_1)$. And call the radius $r$ (which is 32, but my answer will be more general). The center of the second circle is $(x_2, y_2)$. You want to know the location of the intersections between the two circles. Here goes:

1. $y_2 = y_1 + r$, because you've put the second circle one radius higher. And $x_1 = x_2$, because the two centers are vertically aligned.
2. The intersection point must be at height $y_3 = y_1 + \frac{r}{2}$, because it's halfway (in height) between $y_1$ and $y_2$.
3. The intersection point $(x_3, y_3)$ must have distance $r$ to the two circle centers. Writing that for the first circle center, we have

$$
\sqrt{ (x_3 - x_1)^2  + (y_3 - y_1)^2 } = r = \sqrt{r^2}.
$$

which comes, from a long chain of steps, from Pythagoras' Theorem.

If two numbers have the same square root, they're the same number, so 
$$
(x_3 - x_1)^2  + (y_3 - y_1)^2  = r^2
$$

Now by step 2, we know that $y_3 - y_1$ is $r/2$,  So we can say
$$
 (a - x_1)^2  + (r/2)^2  = r^2\\
 (a - x_1)^2  + r^2/4  = r^2 \\
 (a - x_1)^2  = \frac{3}{4} r^2.
$$
That means that $(a - x_1)$ must be either $\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} r$ or its negative.

In your case, this means that the  intersection point is 
$$
\sqrt{ \frac{3}{4} } 32 \approx 27.71
$$
to the left or right  of your circle centers, and the $y$-coordinate is 16 units greater than the first circle center. So 
$$
(x_3, y_3) \approx (x_1 \pm 27.71, y_1 + 16). 
$$